# Distributing one million oracle rows using a webservice

Tags: java, oracle, web-services, caching

How can I distribute a million rows (15 small columns) from an oracle database 
as a web service?

The web service can be simultaneously accessed by 100 concurrent consumers and I cant have any pagination logic for this as the data needs to be sent across in a single go.

This will be hosted in an enterprise grade hardware and our technology stack is based on Java/Tomcat/Oracle.

Comment: why does everyone need ALL data in one go? even with 15 small columns, this would be several megabytes of data for each call.

Comment: Are you using a OR mapping layer or just JDBC? If you're using JDBC you can use scrollable result set to fetch data and if you're specific JPA provider you can still achieve scrollable results and then you can stream this data to client without incurring any overhead on memory and CPU usage.

Comment: why can't you use paging?

Comment: The consumers of data needs the data in a single go and they are not ok with pagination.I am currently streaming the data using a scrollable result set, but was thinking if there are any better ways, like caching it in some thing like an ehcache etc